# Add the word Appendix to header

Tags: header-footer, memoir, appendices, appendix, header

I am completing the template for my PhD thesis. Everything works as expected, except the appendix header.

So far, it only displays the title: 
"**A Journal articles**". What I want instead is: "**Appendix A Journal articles**".

The document class is *memoir* and here is an MWE showing the problem:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

%%%%%%%%% HEADER AND FOOTER FORMAT  %%%%%%%%%

\def\hffont{\sffamily\small}
\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{myruled}{\hffont\thepage}{}{\hffont\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{myruled}{\hffont\rightmark}{}{\hffont\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
    \nouppercaseheads
    \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{\space}
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{\space}
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\pagestyle{myruled}
\copypagestyle{cleared}{myruled}      % When \cleardoublepage, use myruled instead of empty
\makeevenhead{cleared}{\hffont\thepage}{}{} % Remove leftmark on cleared pages
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}            % No page number on plain even pages (chapter begin)
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}  

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Test on header}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

I hope you can help me to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please remember to give us a minimal working example, which most importantly doesn't involve inputting any files that we don't have access to.  It'll make it much easier to help you.

Comment: You are right, but the files to input are not necessary. I showed the code to make clear how I call the appendix.

Comment: I tried to run your MWE but there were so many errors. Please provide code, in one file,  from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows your problem and that we can run.

Comment: Hi! I will try to upload an easier MWE because I cannot put the entire code, it will be enormous. I didn't put it in a first instance because I thought the problem was rather general.

Comment: Done, I added an MWE that shows the problem and can be run. I hope you can help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the new MWE --- most helpful.

Maybe the following edited version of your MWE will do what you want.

```
% appendixheaderprob.tex SE 518282 add Appendix to header

\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

%%%%%%%%% HEADER AND FOOTER FORMAT  %%%%%%%%%

\def\hffont{\sffamily\small}
\makepagestyle{myruled}
\makeheadrule{myruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{myruled}{\hffont\thepage}{}{\hffont\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{myruled}{\hffont\rightmark}{}{\hffont\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{myruled}{}{}{}
%%%%%% new code
\makepagestyle{appruled}
\makeheadrule{appruled}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makeevenhead{appruled}{\hffont\thepage}{}{\hffont\appendixname~\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{appruled}{\hffont\appendixname~\rightmark}{}{\hffont\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{appruled}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{appruled}{}{}{}
%%%% end new code
\makepsmarks{myruled}{
    \nouppercaseheads
    \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{\space}
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{\space}
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
\createplainmark{appendix}{both}{\appendixname}
}
\pagestyle{myruled}
\copypagestyle{cleared}{myruled}      % When \cleardoublepage, use myruled instead of empty
\makeevenhead{cleared}{\hffont\thepage}{}{} % Remove leftmark on cleared pages
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}            % No page number on plain even pages (chapter begin)
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}  

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\blindtext[10]

\appendix
\pagestyle{appruled}  %%%% new code
\chapter{Test on appendix header}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. I see the logic behind it, but it doesn't do what expected. Does it for work for you?

Comment: It is working actually! Thank you :D