# Adding the word "Appendix" to BOTH table of contents and the header of the appendix page

Tags: appendix

I need the word "Appendix" on both (1)Table of contents and (2) the appendix page to read "Appendix A.mytitleFirstApp" instead of the current "A.mytitleFirstApp". I found the solution to (1) at [Adding the word "APPENDIX" to Table of Contents in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44858/adding-the-word-appendix-to-table-of-contents-in-latex) but the solutions of (2) at [Adding to the appendix title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121895/adding-to-the-appendix-title) and [Add the word Appendix to header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518282/add-the-word-appendix-to-header) does not work for me. MWE as follows.

````
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}%title
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{mychp2}

\begin{appendices}% I didnt use \appendix because I wanted the word "Appendix" to appear in table of contents too
\chapter{First}
\chapter{sec}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}```
Thank you
````

Comment: From your MWE, I did see 'Appendix' in the header of the appendix page. I didn't see the form "A,mytitleFirstApp" appear.

Comment: i realised i have another command suppressing the words "chapter" and "appendix" for the headings. Thank you.