# Formatting Appendix in Table of Contents For Thesis

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, thesis, report, appendix

I have

%-----------------------APPENDICES----------------------------%

```
\phantomsection
```

\begin{appendices}
\subfile{subfiles/appendices}
\end{appendices}

The output is [image]

But my aim is to have Appendix A        14 (only one time)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I take it you actually have more than one appendix, you just want to lose the TOC entry.  Assuming you are using the appendix package, add `\appendixtocoff` (page 4 of manual).  Also,  the phantom section is redundant.

Comment: Now I got my appendix to show once but it's called A, not Appendix A in the table of contents. This is my TOC portion of the dissertation.tex: % Table of Contents 



\appendix
\subfile{subfiles/appendices}

Comment: Also, I'm using UGA dissertation LaTeX template, which can be found here: https://github.com/DigiUGA/UGA-Dissertation-LaTeX-Template

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644560/adding-the-word-appendix-to-both-table-of-contents-and-the-header-of-the-appen?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C73.9404